# d3 timeseries, reading date from data, counting entries by date

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to to build a time-series line in d3, using date for the x axis and the number of entries per date as the y axis. I'm having trouble moving the date part of the data object through a date formatter, then a scale, then into my line.

See it in Codepen http://codepen.io/equivalentideas/pen/HaoIs/

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
            var data = [{"title":"1","date":"20140509"},{"title":"2)","date":"20140401"},{"title":"3","date":"20140415"},{"title":"4","date":"20140416"},{"title":"5","date":"20140416"},{"title":"6","date":"20140422"},{"title":"7","date":"20140422"},{"title":"8","date":"20140423"},{"title":"9","date":"20140423"},{"title":"10","date":"20140423"},{"title":"11","date":"20140502"},{"title":"12","date":"20140502"}

            var width = "100%",
                height = "8em";

            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

            // X Scale
            var x = d3.time.scale()
                .range([0, width]);

            // Y Scale
            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height, 0]);

            // define the line
            var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {
                    return x(d.date);
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                    return y(+d);
                })


            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            });

            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
            y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d; }));

            // build the svg canvas
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height);

            // build the line
            svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line);
```

Currently I get a js console error

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN"
```

Comment: So, what is the problem in your code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment jhyap, I've included the error at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem inside jsfiddle?

Comment: made it in code pen, added to the question. Thanks again, that was a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few other issues going on here. First, the width/height are not numbers, so the yScale and xScale ranges are invalid (that's why you get the "NaN" in the line path).

This is bad:

```
var width = "100%",
height = "8em";
```

Because these will not have valid, numerical ranges as required by the following scale definitions:

```
// X Scale
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

// Y Scale
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
```

...what does "8em" to 0 mean in a numerical svg path coordinate? So, make them numbers instead:

```
var width = 500,
height = 100;
```

After you fix that, you'll still have errors because your mapping for the y values isn't going to work. You want a histogram of the counts for the different dates. You should generate the data that way and feed it into the line generator.

```
var generateData = function(data){
    var newData = [];
    var dateMap = {};
    data.forEach(function(element){
        var newElement;
        if(dateMap[element.date]){
            newElement = dateMap[element.date];
        } else {
            newElement = { date: parseDate(element.date), count: 0 };
            dateMap[element.date] = newElement;
            newData.push(newElement);
        }
        newElement.count += 1;
    });

    newData.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime();
    });

    return newData;
};
```

Once you fix those two things it should work. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/j3LzY/

Answer (score 1):

You have not used `parseDate`. You are missing this :

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});
```

Have a look at this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

Comment: I've added that to the script, but unfortunately it it still returns `Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN" `

Answer (score 1):

Some obvious visible problems:

1) You are not appending your svg to any part of the `body` or `div`. You should have a line look like this:

```
d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
```

2) I doubt `d3` can understand your definition for `width` and
    `height`. The width and height is the definition of chart size

3) I think there has no need for the `dateParse` as `d3` will internally do it for you.

Finally, check the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) provided by Niranjan.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It got out of sync with the codepen one. Fixed the body select for the svg. Those width and height definitions do work, you can see it getting rendered into the page at http://codepen.io/equivalentideas/pen/HaoIs/ .